# as3 marquee select drag multiple child objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can anyone tell me how to achieve marquee selection effect with AS3 to select multiple movieclips by drawing a dynamic rectangle around them and then drag and drop them anywhere?

Comment: How detailed of an answer are you looking for?   From a high level view, track the initial mouse down point then every frame between mouseDown and the next mouseUp draw/redraw a rectangle so it matches the current mouse position and the initial mouse position. on mouse up detect all the applicable movieclips that are contained within your rectangle - store that list somewhere temporarily.  Add some logic to handle when one of your mc's from your list is mouse downed. then startDrag() them all.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices thanks 4 the reply, hav already done the rectangular part, stored the hitTestObjects in an array but on mousedown on any of the mcs in the array is only dragging that particular mc, not the other ones

Comment: Temporarily transfer all of the clips you want to move into another MovieClip and drag that. Or, don't really do a startDrag() type drag. Instead, adjust x and y based on the delta of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `startDrag()` if you need multiple objects to be draggable, since it only allows one object to be dragged at a time. Instead, listen for mouse events and do the moving manually:

```
var oldX:int;
var oldY:int;
var dragging:Boolean = false;

function onMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    dragging = true;
    oldX = evt.stageX;
    oldY = evt.stageY;
}

function onMouseMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (!dragging) return;
    var dX:int = evt.stageX - oldX;
    var dY:int = evt.stageY - oldY;
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedClips.length; i++) {
        var clip:DisplayObject = selectedClips[i];
        clip.x += dX;
        clip.y += dY;
    }
    oldX = evt.stageX;
    oldY = evt.stageY;
}

function onMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    dragging = false;
}
```

This code assumes that:

1. Your array of selected objects is called `selectedClips`.
2. Your array of selected objects all inherit from `DisplayObject`.
3. You have added event listeners on all draggable objects for the `MOUSE_DOWN`, `MOUSE_MOVE`, and `MOUSE_UP` mouse events which call these functions.

If any of those three conditions are not met, update my code or your code to work properly. Also, if you need to do any additional handling when the objects are dropped, you can use the mouse up handler to add custom code.